# What is the difference between DiskSpaceLabel and ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, diskspace

There are 2 pages where Inno Setup shows the required disk space: `wpSelectDir` and `wpSelectComponents`. On the `wpSelectComponents` page everything is shown correctly, but it's not on the `wpSelectDir` page.

What is the difference between `DiskSpaceLabel` and `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel`? Aren't those the same?
I understand that the `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel` shows the sum of all the components checked. What does `DiskSpaceLabel` show then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DiskSpaceLabel` displays the minimal space needed for the application. It includes only the files that are installed unconditionally (those that do not belong to any components or tasks, etc).

The `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel` adds the files belonging to the selected components to the size calculation.

Both calculations reflect the [`ExtraDiskSpaceRequired` directive](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_extradiskspacerequired).

Note that `Check` parameters are not considered for the calculation. Neither `DestDir` parameter is (so temporary files are also included). The `dontcopy` flag is not considered either (which you have [reported](https://groups.google.com/g/innosetup/c/o_Epia4tKpw)).